# php function on page load

Tags: php, html

I have 2 functions that makes menu links active/inactive:

```
function disableCtrl() {
    echo 'style="background: #999999;" onclick="return false;"';
}
function enableCtrl() {
    echo ' ';
}
```

I'm using them like this:

```
<li><a href="#" <?php if (@$_POST['submit']){disableCtrl();} if (@$_GET['guest'] == "add") {enableCtrl();} ?> >MenuButton</a></span></li>
```

The only problem I have is that menu links must be disabled by default (when the page is loaded).

When I tried to write `<?php disableCtrl(); if (@$_POST['submit'])...`, the button became perma-disabled.

Is there a way to make it work, maybe with JavaScript or something else?

Comment: JavaScript is not better solution?

Comment: @userNOID i'm too bad js, but ill try. can you give any suggestions?

Comment: what action should cause the menu links to become enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put the 'guest' check as if and the default(disabled)mode as else.

```
   <li><a href="#" <?php if ($_GET['guest']== "add"){enableCtrl();} else {disableCtrl();} ?>>MenuButton</a></li>
```

---

Or with a ternairy (= short if/else-> [condition ? ifTrue : ifFalse] )

```
<li><a href="#" <?php $_GET['guest']=="add" ? enableCtrl() : disableCtrl() ?>>MenuButton</a></li>
```

In combination with disabled (which is made for this exact situation):

```
<li><a href="#" <?=($_GET['guest']=="add" ? 'disabled="disabled"' : '')?>>MenuButton</a></li>
```

Comment: Wow, didn't mentioned about it. Works just perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to vary, say, with every load of a page, use a server-side technology such as php. If you want it to vary within one page load, I.e. in response to user interaction, use a client-side technology I.e. JavaScript.

To attempt to answer the original question, or at least give you some pointers, you want something a bit like:

```
<ul id="menu" style="display: none;"><li><a href="">...</a></li>...</ul>
<a id="btn" href="#">disable menu</a>

<script>
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('menu').setAttribute('style', 'display: block');
}
</script>
```

That's not perfect (in practice, for one thing, you don't want to just point your link to "#" since that won't do anything for those with javascript disabled) but it's a pointer in the right direction. The jQuery equivalent would be something like:

```
<script>
$('#btn').click(function() { $('#menu').hide(); });</script>
</script>
```

if that's more appealing, check out jQuery.

Comment: so is it possible to make this with js only?

Comment: almost certainly, if you can expand your requirements slightly, one of us can tell you how. can you describe the intended behaviour?

Comment: I have 3 menu links that are disabled when you load the page. They should be enabled when you click "add" menu link, and disabled again after submitting form.

Comment: So you could certainly use a javascript approach. You could also use a server-side approach, pointing your "add" link to a script (e.g. php) that carries out this action. Ideally, you would do both. If you're unfamiliar with javascript, start with a framework such as jquery which abstracts away a lot of the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that php is server side so you can use printf to put your javascript into your page.

```
printf("<script>Here is my javascript code</script>");
```

I do this a lot with the mapping services.
For example reading in locations from a database and making markers:

```
    public function MarkerGoogle($s)
    {
        $str  = sprintf("\r\n   var amkr%d = new google.maps.Marker();\r\n", $s);

        // More php code here …
```